# How to write in an file in MSIL code

Tags: .net, cil

I have a aspx webpage which uses an assembly mine (which mades a custom authentification).
I would like to modify MSIL code (so just with ILDASM/ILASM tools) of my assembly in order to log something in a file.

I have tried to add this at the end of the authentification method of my assembly :

```
IL_0034:  ldstr      "C:\\path_to_my_website\\log.txt"
IL_0039:  newobj     instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.StreamWriter::.ctor(string)
IL_003e:  stloc.1
IL_003f:  ldloc.1
IL_0040:  ldstr      "test"
IL_0045:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter::Write(string)
IL_004a:  nop
IL_004b:  ldloc.1
IL_004c:  callvirt   instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.TextWriter::Close()
IL_0051:  nop
```

ILASM does not find any error, and the CLR does not throw any exception at runtime, but the file is not created or modified ! :(

Any idea ?

Comment: If it's your assembly, why don't you simply just add the logging in the actual code ?

Comment: Because I'm learning MSIL code, and the final purpose is a lot more tricky.

Comment: Have you tried calling `Flush()` before `Close()`? Some streams don't flush when they close, which is a bit silly...

Comment: ILASM like any assembler, just assembles. You need to run PEVerify to ensure your code is valid and verifiable.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil). Its intended for loading assemblies as files, mucking with their contents, and saving the results. Specifically [this example](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil%3aFAQ) adds debug tracing to methods of an existing assembly.

Comment: @CodeInChoas: yes it does. Mono.Cecil runs equally fine on Mono and .net.

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

- if you literally added that IL to the very end of the method, then it will all be after a `ret` instruction (or other unreachable location), so nothing will happen (and the IL probably won't be valid either).  Have you tried running peverify on your assembly to make sure that it's valid?
- is there any reason that the authentication code might not be run?  What happens if you try to step through the code in a debugger?